# Ionic 2 app doesn't responde after modal dismiss

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, modal-dialog, ionic2

I have a modal in my Ionic 2 app. In this modal, clicking on a button, a confirmation prompt ("Are you sure?") pops up. By clicking yes, I do certain operations, then dismiss the modal by calling this method:

```
close() {
    this._viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

and `_viewCtrl` is the property of my class, which i defined this way in the constructor:

```
constructor(
          public _nav: NavController,
          public _viewCtrl: ViewController,
          public _profile: Profile,
          params: NavParams) { ... }
```

My problem is that behind the modal I have a "3 Tabs Page", sort of. All works well, the 3 tabs are just fine, my modal is ok, it dismisses as it should, the problem is that when the modal is dismissed the 3 tabs break! They freeze on the second tab (which is the one that calls the modal)! Even if I click on tab 1 and 3, I see only the content for tab 2, and I can do nothing.

I'm pretty sure the operations before the dismiss shouldn't be a problem. I found that if I comment out the `this.close();` part, and everything goes fine! The modal doesn't close, but I can close it by hand (**with the same function, that's the strange thing!**) then I return to the tabs page and the tabs are just fine.

What is happening to the app?

PS. No error is shown in the console!

Answer (score 0):

If you check in the console you will see the modal overlay is still there. That's why when you click on any button on your app, you got no reaction cos you click on the transparent overlay.

Comment: I see. So what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue now, where I had the dismissal of a `Modal` working before with Ionic 2 Beta 6, but on the latest Beta 10 it isn't working anymore.

How my logic worked was:

- Do server call (while displaying progress with the `Loading` component
- When call returns from server, then dismissing the `Loading` and then the `Modal`, but calling them in a synchronous fashion

Now this doesn't work with latest Beta.  What I had to do was:

```
this.loading.onDismiss(() => {
    this.viewController.dismiss();
});
this.loading.dismiss();
```

I got this workaround from here:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6325